# Python Flask Restful Api Cors Issue

Tags: python, flask-restful, flask-cors

I built a post api with flask and deployed in windows server. Whenever I hit the api from postman, it is working fine. but when i hit the api from frontend(Ionic). It shows cors error. I added flask cors on server side. I am not sure, is it from server side or client side problem. The get methods are working fine from postman and frontend also. Frontend developer told me that it's coming from backend. he tried all most every solution from frontend. I attached some of my code below:

run.py

```
from flask_cors import CORS
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*":{"origins":"*"}})
```

users.py

```
 class GetOtp(Resource):
    def post(self):
       json_data = request.get_json()
       data = otpSchema.load(json_data).data
       #I call a third party api, SMS service provider here.
       return {'message':'OTP XXXXX sent successful'},200
```

Comment: CORS(app, resources={r"/": {"origins": "*"}})

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my flask API, this is what solved the issue for me.

```py
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```